# print in jframe and immediately exitting

Tags: java

i designed a small game in java. Now, the ending point condition of the game is when some collision occurs(it might be really lengthy to explain the whole thing).I wish to print "game over" on the gaming screen i.e the jframe along with the score.and immediately i need to exit from the code. To display score and"game over" before exitting, i made the thread sleep for 6 seconds. In the output, the thread does sleep for 6 seconds but my game over and score statement is not getting printed. When i remove thread.sleep and System.exit(0) then these statements are displayed but then i dnt understand how do i exit my code.pls help.here is what i tried:

```
    if(collision_occurs)
    {   
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        g2.setFont(new Font("serif",Font.BOLD+Font.ITALIC,50));
        time_taken=(endTime-startTime)/1000000000;
        String tym=String.valueOf(time_taken);
        g2.drawString("GAME OVER", 100, 50);
        g2.drawString("SCORE= ",100, 100);
        g2.drawString(tym, 300, 100);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
          System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: no change is observed even then......its gettin really fussy pls help

Answer (score 2):

You should **never** call Thread.sleep() from the EDT.

Instead, set up a Timer that exits after a certain amount of time. Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Edit: Here is more info on the EDT: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: this could be a comment, don't you think so?

Comment: This is the correct way to do this; create a Timer object, passing it a runnable that kills the program. As a side note, it would appear as if the OP is calling `Thread.sleep()` from inside `paintComponent()`, which is not called from the EDT. Still, calling Thread.sleep() from paintComponent() is guaranteed to freeze up the GUI, causing the problem described in the OP.

Comment: @Frakcool It is the correct **answer** to the question that the OP asked, so no, I don't think this should be a comment. Note that the comment you left would still have a call to Thread.sleep() on the EDT, which is A Very Bad Thing.

Comment: @jedyobidan The paintComponent() method is indeed called from the EDT. That's the reason it freezes up your gui...

Comment: @user3694166 This is the first result for googling "java EDT": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: KevinWorkman would you mind editing your post, so I can upvote and take out the downvote? Adding the EDT link you provided here? also @user3694166 after reading both links from Kevin, his answer is the correct.